# Redirect based on user input

Tags: javascript

I have 20 different pages. Let's say that IDs of the pages are for example: `mysite.com/page1`, `mysite.com/page2` and so on...

I need to create an input field where the user can enter numbers, and if he inputs number 16 for example, it will redirect him to `mysite.com/page16`.

I believe that this is possible with JavaScript. Has anyone got any advice?

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function()
  {
    window.location.href = "http://www.yourdomain.com/page"+document.getElementById("url").value
  };
}
```

```html
<input id="url" value="">
<button id="btn">Go!</button>
```

Comment: Your solution seems great and it's working perfectly in code snippet, but when I try to test it in in my empty html document it doesn't work at all. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the screenshot: https://postimg.org/image/ymacsuflt/

Comment: Hm. Show me pls console in your browser, when you click on button. Also you can remove jquery.

Comment: Console says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at index.html:7

Comment: I think I found solution with this: 
`<script>
window.onload = function(){ 

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function()
{
  window.location.href = "http://www.yourdomain.com/page"+document.getElementById("url").value
};

};

</script>
`

Comment: How can I validate empty field? "required" shows an error but it still redirects user to first page even If the field is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You could use window.redirect to your desired page

```
var input_number = document.getElementById('input_id').value
url = "mysite.com/page" + input_number;
window.location=url;
```

Where `input_id` is the id of your input box

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JavaScript (no libraries) you can use the following script (ES6).

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#input');
input.addEventListener('change', event => {
  var url = `mysite.com/page${input.value}`;
  alert(url);
  window.location = url;
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" name="page" min="1" max="16" value="0"></input>
```